# Proof with finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ will be a finite group and quantity of elements is odd number. Prove that for any $g \in G$ exists $h \in G$ such that $h^2=g$.

So i know that $\mbox{ord}(G) = 2n + 1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But I have no idea how do it this proof. I will be grateful for your hint and idea.

Comment: Hint: Consider suitable powers of $g$ as candidates for $h$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $g^{2n+1}=1$, we have $g=g^{2n+2}=(g^{n+1})^2.$

Comment: So we can take $h = g^{n+1}$ and it is end of task?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little different way.

The order of $G$ is odd $|G|=2n-1 $ while  $n \in \mathbb R$ .

Let $a,b,c \in G$ and lets assume that  $a \ne b $
and $a^2=b^2=c$ so $a^4=b^4=c^2$  and $a^{2n+2}=b^{2n+2}=c^n$ because  $|G|=2n-1 $ 
than $a^{2n-1}=e$ for every $a\in G$.

Therefore for every $a\in G$ $a^2$ has different value.

Comment: Different value than what? You mean that the set of elements $a^2$ for $a\in G$ has the same number of elements as $G$? And even though I can see how to finish your argument for this, you seem to be using precisely the fact that $a^{2n+2} = a$ to do this, which would finish the proof anyway.